# can the ui.inputfield have the data from both text box and input displayed overlaying each other?

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, unity3d-2dtools

I have a Unity Droid app with an ui.inputfield. I am giving the user the ability to enter numbers or move a slider. In either case I need to have the slider data appear in the inputfield or update the slider position with the number typed into the inputfield. I can get the data from both the inputfield or the slider but I need to have the data displayed. My main concern is **can I have the data from both inputs displayed at the exact same location as the inputfield, like on top**?
I can not find any examples of the data display on top of the input field. Is this the correct way to think about this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are callbacks whenever the user changes a `UI.Slider` or finishes entering a value in a `UI.InputField`:

- [`UI.Slider.onValueChanged`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Slider-onValueChanged.html)
- [`UI.InputField.onEndEdit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.InputField-onEndEdit.html)

So yes you could link them to each other like e.g.

```c#
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputField inputField;
    public Slider slider;

    private void Awake()
    {
        inputField.onEndEdit.AddListener(OnInputFieldChanged);
        slider.onValueChanged .AddListener( OnSliderChanged);

        OnSliderChanged(slider.value);
    }

    private void OnInputFieldChanged(string newText)
    {
        if (float.TryParse(newText, out var value))
        {
            value = Mathf.Clamp(value, slider.minValue, slider.maxValue);

            inputField.text = value.ToString("F");
            slider.value = value;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Input Format Error!", this);
            slider.value = Mathf.Clamp(0, slider.minValue, slider.maxValue);
            inputField.text = slider.value.ToString("F");
        }
    }

    private void OnSliderChanged(float newValue)
    {
        inputField.text = newValue.ToString("F");
    }
}
```

---

[image]

Comment: This is the answer! Thank you. I spent 3 days on this and couldn't see the trees for the forest.